# Prove that the Möbius ladder and the toroidal ladder are non-isomorphic graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

I just gave this problem on my graph theory final, and I can't wait to see what innovative approaches my students come up with.

The two ladders are defined to be the only $3$-regular graphs that can be obtained by adding two new edges to the $2\times n$ grid, where $n\ge 3$.  (The names suggest which ladder is which.)

So the problem is to prove that ${\mathcal T}_n$ (toroidal ladder) is not isomorphic to ${\mathcal M}_n$ (Möbius ladder) for each $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For even $n$ the toroidal ladder is bipartite, the Möbius ladder is not.
For odd $n$ the Möbius ladder is bipartite, the toroidal ladder is not.

Comment: Exactly.  This is the simplest and most direct solution (also the solution I came up with).  Nicely done.

Comment: Thanks. It is a nice problem, not too hard to solve, but not immediately obvious either. Please report elegant solutions by your students (if they are different).

Comment: Also, one is planar and the other is not.

Comment: @hbm Absolutely, and this was the most common response I received among students who got at least partial credit.  Few were actually able to prove this however.  Many just stated it.